# Inline style vs "inline style" . What is the difference?

Tags: html

What is the difference between `height="50"` VS `style="height:50px"` ?

And `height="50"` VS `style="height:50"`?

I am always confused by this.

Comment: The former is not a style.

Comment: Are you asking about height specifically or presentational attributes in general?

Comment: @Quentin he asking about presentation attributes, as I guess

Comment: @Khazratbek — We can all guess. I'm asking the OP to clarify their actual meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Presentation-related attributes such as `height="50"` where the original way to specify presentation details of HTML elements.

However, they have since been deprecated in favour of CSS, via the `style`, `class` and `id` attributes, which give a lot more flexibility that the original attributes (at the very least because CSS can be extended without touching the definition of HTML itself, but of course also because you get the "cascading" part, as well as multiple units, media-queries, and much more).

You should thus generally avoid such attributes in HTML.

The only exception is HTML in e-mail, as many clients support those attributes but not the CSS versions.

Note that you should generally avoid `style` attributes as well, in favour of separate CSS, and `class` and/or `id` attributes. This allows you to completely separate the HTML and CSS, and makes it easier to change the presentation of your page without touching the HTML (or the code that generates it).

Also, in CSS (and thus in `style` attributes), you **must** specify units (except for 0), so `height: 50` is not valid, you should use `height: 50px` (or another unit).

Answer (score 0):

Using `style` attribute you add rich CSS to the element. Some styling can not be added using HTML attributes. For example `<div style="background-color: #ff00ff; float: right">` is impossible with plain HTML attributes.

Comment: he asked not is it rich element or no. He asked what the difference between *height="50"* and *style="height:50px"*